# Python float variable bit manipulation

Tags: python, c++, floating-point, bit-manipulation

How can I translate the following C++ code into Python to perform bit manipulation with float variables, where `y` is a declared as `float`?

```
long i  = * ( long * ) &y;
```

Comment: FWIW, unless you are using C++20, this code is not legal C++ code.

Comment: @NathanOliver how is it legal in C++20?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Looks like it isn't. I forgot you need to use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) to make it legal.